# devServer proxy in config throws 404

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, webpack

I have this in `src/vue.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'http://localhost:8081',
        changeOrigin: true,
      },
    },
  },
};
```

and I'm calling the api with

```
  axios.get('/api/parts')
    .then(result => commit('updateParts', result.data))
    .catch(console.error);
```

But I just keep getting

> Error: "Request failed with status code 404"

And I can see the request is being made to port 8080 instead of 8081

I can access the api in the browser with no problems

How can I debug this?

Comment: How are your backend routes structured? Does your backend expect the /api as prefix? If not try ```pathRewrite: { '^/api': ''}``` as additional option

Comment: @FrankProvost I tried adding `pathRewrite` but it made no difference (even after restarting the server). Do you mean the routes for the api or for the web app?

Comment: I'm talking about the routes for the api. What url do you open in your browser to see the api result? localhost:8081/api/parts or without the /api?

Comment: @FrankProvost its with the `/api`

Comment: Have you tried defining the target as target: 'http://localhost:8081/api'?

Comment: @FrankProvost Ye, I get the same result. Its like the app is just ignoring the proxy altogether (there is no trace of any attempt to request at 8081 anywhere(

Comment: What version of the vue-cli did you use to generate the project? Are you sure your way to edit the config is matching the version you've installed?

Comment: @FrankProvost `vue --version` gives me `3.3.0` - do you know where I can check whether I am using the right method?

Comment: Think I had the same issue going through the same tutorial on pluralsight! vue.js Fundamentals as stuck with the same error. My problem seemed to be that the server had change the port after stopping and starting! so was testing on port 8080 instead of the new port 8082. very strange. Checking this and going to the new app location on the new port and then it works

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `vue.config.js` is not supposed to be in the src folder. It must be in the root of your project. Simply move the file.

The configuration reference for the server can be found here: https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#devserver-proxy but it seems you're actually doing it right. The file is just at the wrong folder.

Comment: OMG. this saved me. i keep being pointed to other port while modifying all the things i can modify in order to get my axious working!! thanks!

Comment: glad i could help :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue after trying a couple of combinations finally I figured it out.

I am using `Axios` and my application is running at port `8080`

**main.js:**

`axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:8080/api/'`

**vue.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    devServer: {
      proxy: 'https://reqres.in'
    }
}
```

**My Vue Component**

```
this.axios.get("users")
   .then(response => {
    this.items = response.data.data;
    this.isLoading = false;
})
```

**Browser's Network tab:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

it is not right, if you use proxy, your remote address must be same as request url and port, so your vue.config.js should be edited like below:

```
proxy: {
          '/api': {
              target: 'http://localhost:8080',
              changeOrigin: true
          }
```

or you can use rewrite attribute like this :

```
proxy: {
          '/api': {
              target: 'http://localhost:8080',
              changeOrigin: true,
              pathRewrite: { '^/api': '/'}
          }
      }
```

the difference is the real request, top will be http://localhost:8080/api/...,  rewrite will be  http://localhost:8080/...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Xiwei Huang :)