# Why is my vue.config.js proxy not working?

Tags: vue.js, config, vue-cli-3

I have a vue cli 3.5.0 project and am trying to add a proxy, but i cant get it to work. the server runs on :5000 and the client on :8080. Below you can see my proxy. But it keeps using :8080 instead of :5000

vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    devServer: {
      proxy: {
        '/api': {
          target: 'http://localhost:5000',
          ws: true,
          changeOrigin: true
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

And this is an example of how I call a request

```
const url = '/api/races/'
const config = {
    headers: {'Authorization': "Bearer " + localStorage.token}
}

class RaceService {
    // Get Races
    static getRaces() {
        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
            try {
                const res = await axios.get(url)
                const races = res.data
                resolve(races)
            } catch (err) {
                reject(err)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Can someone maybe help me? the api requests need to use :5000 instead of :8080

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to use "^/api" instead of "/api"

Comment: I'll be more specific with : https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#devserver-proxy

Answer (score 1):

Check your vue.config.js file location it should not be in the src folder, instead at the root of your project, for details refer : [This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54216516/devserver-proxy-in-config-throws-404)

Answer (score -1):

try **reloading** your **vue** server if you haven't done so

until you start and stop the **vue** server
cause until you do this the vue.config.js is not loaded in,

so do

Ctrl+C in the terminal where your you did npm run serve
and then start again using
`npm run serve`